# Accept arbitrary JSON as RequestBody in Spring

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

As the title suggests, I'd like my controller class to accept (mostly) arbitrary JSON in the RequestBody as part of a POST. Before you ask why I'd want unworkable JSON, it's because the JSON is simply passing through to a storage backend with very minimal processing (only extracting one field).

There are three required fields in this JSON: `data`, `schema`, and `resourceID`. Here's what my request class looks like:

```
public class MyRequestBody implements Serializable {

    private JsonObject data;
    private JsonObject schema;
    private String resourceID;
    ...
```

I already understand the serialization issues that cause this not to work. The reason I don't want to expand this data model further to define fields for `data` and `schema` is that I simply do not know how nested they will be. That is also why I don't simply use `Map<String, String>`.

Is there a simple solution to receiving arbitrary, nested JSON data as part of the `RequestBody`, or am I forced to either write a large, strongly typed data model or accept it as an `Object`, convert to JSON, and do all my field validation somewhere else?

Controller signature for reference:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "test/data", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<StorageData> publishData(@RequestBody MyRequest requestBody) {
```

Here's some example JSON. Where things get dicey are in the `data` and `schema` section where they may contain multiple levels of nesting that I wouldn't be aware of:

```
{
    "data": {
        "display": "bilbo_baggins"
    },
    "resourceID": "0123456789",
    "schema": {
        "type": "record",
        "namespace": "com.org.test",
        "name": "mySchema",
        "fields": [{
            "name": "display",
            "type": "string"
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think I'm following how exactly do you intend to extract these fields from an arbitrary JSON, if you don't know precisely how nested they will be. Care to show an example?

Comment: I added an example. The only field I need to extract is `resourceID` which will always be top-level. The `data` and `schema` fields are the ones causing me issues because I don't know how/if I can accept them without clearly defining what they look like. This application is just saving all the data using the resourceID, but the rest of the content is irrelevant to my application

Comment: You can just use a Map<String, Object>, and get your resourceID out of this map.

Comment: Please note that using a `Map<String, Object>` will cause you numerous validation headaches and would pretty much nullify any benefits you would try to get from a Spring Controller. Why is a single endpoint used for so many different data types? Is this a legacy system you are intending to 'rewrite'? If so, why not do it right and have an endpoint per request type (which likely describes different domain objects and actions anyway)?

Comment: It's really not used for multiple data types, I'm not sure why you think that. Since you need the context, the `schema` field is an Avro schema that is associated with the `data` field. This endpoint is standing in front of a Kafka system, and so they need to be bundled together. I'm trying to write this in such a way where I don't have a large, strongly-typed data model and also so that I can reuse this endpoint for any Kafka topic I want.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

1. You can receive a JsonNode object for an arbitrary JSON

Like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "test/data", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<StorageData> publishData(@RequestBody JsonNode requestBody) {.. }
```

2. Change MyRequestBody class to use JsonNode instead of JsonObject for *data* and *schema*. You don't need to implement Serializable, unless you need it for something else in your code, but it's not needed for receiving Json objects in request.

Comment: Great. How can I add a Serializer or Deserializer to this?